# email validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using razor view in my application.
I am trying to validate my mailID.
I got email pattern format like,

```
 function validateEmail(mail) {
  var emailPattern =  var emailPattern = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
     if (emailPattern.test(mail) == false) {
           $("#emailvalidation").text("Email is not in correct format");
       }
       else if (emailPattern.test(mail) == true) {
        }
     }
```

but If I give this in my function,It is displaying error at the "@" symbol.
can any one help me,how to fix this.

Comment: you have 2 semicolons at the end of that line...

Comment: by mistake I gave two semicolumns,If I give one semi column also,It is showing error.

Comment: you have duplicated variable declaration, try to remove one 'var emailPattern = '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave like,
var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{0,4}$/;
 I used "@" twice. 
it is working fine in my case.

Answer (score 1):

because Razor code blocks are enclosed in @{ ... },
Inline expressions (variables and functions) start with @,
Code statements end with semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line.

```
var emailPattern =  var emailPattern = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
```

To this

```
var emailPattern = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
```

See the associated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjv9k/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
I am trying to restrict the user not to insert more than two domain after the '@'. 

/^[\w-_$\.]+@[\w]+((\.)((\w){2,4})){1,2}$/
```